# Magento rest api, access token

Tags: rest, magento-1.9, access-token

I would like to know if Magento host wiill provide access token even if there are no products or resources added in the admin/ store?  I did not add any products in my store, I have a request token and oauth verifier, but I am unable to get access token? I'm getting http code '0' and no particular error. I'm using the code given in magento site.

```
<?php
/**
```

* Example of products list retrieve using Customer account via Magento REST API. OAuth authorization is used
 */

```
$callbackUrl = "http://127.0.0.1/callback.php";
$temporaryCredentialsRequestUrl = "http://127.0.0.1/magento/magento-1.9/oauth/initiate?oauth_callback=" . urlencode($callbackUrl);
$adminAuthorizationUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1/magento/magento-1.9/admin/oauth_authorize';
$accessTokenRequestUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1/magento/magento-1.9/oauth/token';
$apiUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1/magento/magento-1.9/magento/api/rest';
$consumerKey = '8f86e9bc5c3239180a0b208e02633085';
$consumerSecret = '025384b388b70daad209c31132e7c219';

session_start();
if (!isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && isset($_SESSION['state']) && $_SESSION['state'] == 1) {
    $_SESSION['state'] = 0;
}

try {
    $authType = ($_SESSION['state'] == 2) ? OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_AUTHORIZATION : OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_URI;
    $oauthClient = new OAuth($consumerKey, $consumerSecret, OAUTH_SIG_METHOD_HMACSHA1, $authType);
    $oauthClient->enableDebug();

    if (!isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && !$_SESSION['state']) {
        $requestToken = $oauthClient->getRequestToken($temporaryCredentialsRequestUrl);
        $_SESSION['secret'] = $requestToken['oauth_token_secret'];
        $_SESSION['state'] = 1;
        header('Location: ' . $adminAuthorizationUrl . '?oauth_token=' . $requestToken['oauth_token']);
        exit;
    } else if ($_SESSION['state'] == 1) {
        $oauthClient->setToken($_GET['oauth_token'], $_SESSION['secret']);
        $accessToken = $oauthClient->getAccessToken($accessTokenRequestUrl);
        $_SESSION['state'] = 2;
        $_SESSION['token'] = $accessToken['oauth_token'];
        $_SESSION['secret'] = $accessToken['oauth_token_secret'];
        header('Location: ' . $callbackUrl);
        exit;
    } else {
        $oauthClient->setToken($_SESSION['token'], $_SESSION['secret']);
        $resourceUrl = "$apiUrl/products";
        $oauthClient->fetch($resourceUrl);
        $productsList = json_decode($oauthClient->getLastResponse());
        print_r($productsList);
    }
} catch (OAuthException $e) {
    print_r($e);
    ?>







}
```

Comment: Is possible use REST API without oAuth? @psr

Answer (score 0):

To someone looking for an answer, Magento host does provide access token and secret with or without any inventory/products in the catalog. When the Magento host redirects to the callback url with oauth token and oauth verifier code, I wrote a php script in the redirect page to download the contents of the query string into a file. Thereby I used those contents(token and verifier code) in the request for access token and access secret.

Additionally, I used a Java client for the requests. An excellent library is available in Java called oauth.signpost. A lot of examples are available on the same.

Further, after being redirected to the callback url, the client has to use an asynchronous request to get access token and secret. An asynchronous client can be used from any library or by using threads, sleep mechanism.